# In django whats the difference between mergemigrations and squashmigrations?

Tags: python, django, bitbucket, pipeline, bitbucket-pipelines

When shall we use mergemigrations --meerge/mergemigrations and when to use squashmigrations can we execute these commands via pipeline insteed of each developer in team doing it manually ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us assume that the migration folder has the following migrations.

```
./foo
    ./migrations
        0001_initial.py
        0002_userprofile.py
        0003_article.py
        0004_auto_add.py
```

above are the ordered till now? As we working in team.

- **Developer1** working on the **article** features and he has created a migration **0005_add_name_in_article.py**
- **Developer2** working on the **userprofile** features and he has created the **0005_add_mobile_in_userprofile.py**
- **Developer3** working on the **category** features and he has creatd the **0005_category.py**

##### ***Now that the situation has occurred when***

- **Developer1** will merge the code into **develop** branch, the migration file will be

```
./foo
    ./migrations
        0001_initial.py
        0002_userprofile.py
        0003_article.py
        0004_auto_add.py
        0005_add_name_in_article.py
```

- **Developer2** will merge the code into **develop** branch, the migration file will be

```
./foo
    ./migrations
        0001_initial.py
        0002_userprofile.py
        0003_article.py
        0004_auto_add.py
        0005_add_name_in_article.py
        0005_add_mobile_in_userprofile.py
```

Here, the last two migrations have the same dependence, and this is breaking the order of the migration, while **Developer2** migrating the migration after merging the **develop** branch django will provide the hit to ***merge*** the migration. After running the command, Django will create a new migration, **0006_merge_add_name_in_article_add_mobile_in_userprofile.py**, which is merge the **0005_add_name_in_article.py** and **0005_add_mobile_in_userprofile.py**
The file contains the

```
  dependencies = [
        ('app_name', '0005_add_name_in_article'),
        ('app_name', '0005_add_mobile_in_userprofile'),
    ]
```

Now the **Developer2** local branch has the following migrations.

```
./foo
    ./migrations
        0001_initial.py
        0002_userprofile.py
        0003_article.py
        0004_auto_add.py
        0005_add_name_in_article.py
        0005_add_mobile_in_userprofile.py
        0006_merge_add_name_in_article_add_mobile_in_userprofile.py
```

Now the **Developer2** will raise a PR and merge so that another develop note have and conflict.

- Same process will do **Developer3** for avoiding the migration conflict.

#### What is "merge migration"?

The main aim of the merge migration is to reduce the conflict on the database level while working in collaborative manners. and it will generate the new migration file for managing the order of migrations.

#### What is "squash migration"?

May a question arise in your mind: **how many unnecessary files will be created for migration?"**

- In **merge** migration file, there has not been any operation.
- There may be the table where you have add one column then remove and then re-add it to table the different migration may created
  The main aim of squash migration is to optimize the migration file. but before squashing the migration, please refer to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/migrations/#squashing-migrations) as in some cases it may be cumbersome or raise a migration conflict.

#### Can we execute these commands via pipeline instead of each developer in our team doing it manually?

Nope, as per the above use case of merge and squash migration, We can't do it on pipeline as it developer responsibility to keep migration in ordered and as per the django community all migration should be sync in team so we can not do it in pipeline.